# "Long running" PHP-script fails with "Redirect Status Code: 500" using "header("Location: $url");"

Tags: php

I'm running a cron job once an hour that can initiate multiple "jobs" to finish.
The cron job points to a php file which starts a "background script" that repeats itself multiple times when necessary.
The time to finish each "job" can take unknown amount of time, but always finishes in less than 20 minutes with margin. Therefore the server "max_execution_time" is set to allow script to run for 20 min to prevent timeout.
If the script has 4 jobs where each job takes 10 minutes, the total execution time would exeed 20 minutes.
My thought on how to resolve this, was to use header("Location: $url") after one "job" finished to initiate a new restart of the script for "next job" and get 20 new minutes to work with.

As long as a "job" only takes a couple of minutes, everything works fine. But when it reaches a "job" that takes 12 minutes. The header("Location: $url") fails with *500 Internal Server Error*
Followed by:
*Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*
This happends even if the total amount of exectution time including previous "jobs" is less than 20 minutes.

I don't exceed the cron job redirects and I don't exceed 20 min of execution time (including all current "jobs").
So even if my thought of using header("Location: $url") to prevent future total execution time to exceed 20 min. I already have failure before reaching limit of either amount of redirects or execution time.
What's currently failing is 6 "jobs" and the total execution time of the first 4 is 2,5 minutes. The 5:th job is 12 min. The location redirect to the last 6:th job does not work, as the header("Location: $url") fails after the 5:th job has been running for 12 minutes. Total execution time for all "jobs" until this point is only 14,5 minutes and redirects is 5 (Allowed redirects is 60).
If I switch out the 12 min job to 6 other shorter running jobs, having a total of 10 shorter jobs, everything works fine.
So there seems to be somthing connected to the run time of the script and how header("Location:") work?

I know this solution is not the best (or any good) way to handle this kind of task. But the road led me to this point during the development and finding out why the 500 internal error is occuring would make this solution work while I rewrite a new "job" handler.

Therefore any help would be welcome :)

```php
if ($job != "available") { // this illustrates a check in database if there is any jobs "available" or if all is finished
    return "all jobs finished";
}

$repeating = true;

while ( $repeating == true ) {

    // has different stuff that can take some time to finish
    if($something == true) {
        // run task
        continue;
    }

    if($something_else == true) {
        // run task
        continue;
    }

    // above currently takes between 1 to 12 minutes
    // when finished set $repeating to false to end while loop
    $repeating = false;

}

// here is a log written to file (which never fails)
write_string_to_file($string);

// current job finished, reload this page again, check if there is any jobs left. If jobs left, this initiates new 20 minutes before exectution time timeout?
// ($url is pointing to this page again)
header("Location: $url") // this fails if above while loop takes 12 minutes, which currently is the longest running "job"
```

**Note:** I made a custom 500 error page which pointed me to the header("Location") as the issue, as that gave me following info on what whas requested:

Requested URL: "the $url im actually reloading was presented here"
Redirect Status Code: 500

Worth mentioning. The error also said:
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

So no error log is available at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the Error 500 you're getting is actually related to the script finding its environment different from what it expected.

For example, some session or DB connection expired.

I'd suggest you set `error_reporting` to maximum and add suitable logging for errorlevels (including startup errors).

Without knowing in detail what the jobs do and how they work, it's not likely that the precise cause of error can be guessed. The redirect **works**, as your custom handler demonstrated. The problem is that the *new script instance* is failing.

Another possibility is redirect to a diagnostic script that simply dumps into a file the content of `$_SERVER`, `$_SESSION` etc. . Then, start adding the content of the job manager script to the diagnostic script, until it breaks with a 500 error again.

Comment: Thanks for the input!!!
I think the error_reporting is at max already. It's still in an development environment so no need to hide anything ;)
There is no $_SESSION or "open" connections to the DB. Hmm... I'm writing to DB in parts of the while loop and with my somewhat limited knowledge on the "open connection" to DB topic, I maybe should look for a missed "close" of the db connection? I'll investigate that :)
I'll also look into dumping the content to file as I'm a bit annoyed by this and would find satisfaction in finding what the cause is :)

Answer (score 1):

First you should check the error-logs to get the exact error-message.
Without the exact message we can't provide detailed answers.
Also how about storing the last job somewhere(text-file/database), to continue with the next job.

For example:

```
<?php   
$id_job = 0;
switch($id_job)
{
    case 10:
        job1();
    case 20:
        job2();
}
```

after each job just set the id_job of the current/done job and add 10 before entering the switch/case.

Comment: The easier solution would be to don't break after the first case, so you could simply continue with the next one. But of course, if he is interested in a more "elegant" way, he should use breaks. Also he should rework the structure then.

Comment: If your `$id_job` is 10, he will do both `job1()` and `job2()` Don't think that is the point in OP's code

Comment: Thought he will continue with the next job. For example: The last job was job1 and id_job is now set to 10. So he will continue with case 20/job2 and so one. If the execution fails, he can load the stored value to continue with the next one.

Comment: Nope the code will execute job2 instantly after job1. See [here](http://ideone.com/lpQmPx)

Comment: Unfortunately the logs are empty. I forgot to add that it also says:
"Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."



I’m storing logs which is what actually work just before the "redirect".  I'm also storing the progress of the "job" in the DB during the "while loop" to be able split the "job" into smaller chunks in the future. That’s however the new version of this "job handler" that I'll have to work on. Getting the redirect to work now would however get the it to work again while I finish the new version.

Comment: Using your script (if I understand it correct), all jobs must finish in "one run" which could exceed the max_ecectution time if another long "job" is added. Or the page must be accessed/reloaded to get new execution_time, which is what I'm currently have issues with... I think at least :)
I know adding a separate cron job to check for unfinished "jobs" would solve the issue. But there is a queue that needs to be taken into consideration that makes it "not so easy" for me :(

As a new user to here, I must thank you all for the help and input. Way faster response than I was expecting!

Comment: How do I insert line breaks in comments?... they are barely readable in one chunk :)